# Should PYTHONPATH include ./build/*?

Tags: python, python-2.7, cython, distutils, pythonpath

Running

```
$ python setup.py build_ext
```

with the usual Cython extension configuration creates a `build` directory and places the compiled modules deep within it.

How is the Python interpreter supposed to find them now? Should `PYTHONPATH` include those sub-sub-directories? It seems kludgy to me. Perhaps this is meant to work differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, when you write a package containing Cython code, [your `setup.py` will contain something similar to this](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html):

```
setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize("example.pyx")
)
```

(there are some variations, but that's the general idea). When you run

```
python setup.py install
```

or

```
python setup.py install --user
```

You will see it creates binary files (with extensions based on your OS - on mine it will be `example.so`) and copies them to the standard installation directory (also depending on your OS).

These binary files are therefore already in the import path of your Python distribution, and it can `import` them like regular modules.

Consequently, you do not need to add the build directory to the path. Just install (possibly with `--user`, or use virtualenv, if you're developing), and let the extensions be imported the regular way.

Answer (score 2):

You will find the information here https://docs.python.org/3.5/install/

Build is an intermediary result before python actually install the module. Put in pythonpath the paths to the library that is, for instance:

```
<dir>/local/lib/python
```

if you use the "home" installation technique and dir is the directory you have chosen, ex

```
/home/user2
```